# Inserir dados no firebase a partir do AlertDialog

Tags: android, firebase, alertdialog

Galera estou com uma duvida, queria saber se tem como armazenar dados no firebase  a partir de um AlertDialog customizado?

Se sim queria a ajuda de vcs para criar uma logica e fazer essa ideia acontecer, acho que isso para quem esta começando ajudaria muito.

Obg a todos que estao determinados a ajudar

Comment: Eder, você já salvou dados no firebase antes, se sim, como faz ? utiliza uma classe model para isso ?

Comment: Opa Eduardo, sim ja salvei em outro projetos mas foi coisas simples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, partindo do principio que você já criou o seu alert ou sabe como criar pois não postou código algum, você pode fazer o seguinte:
Supondo que o usuário digite alguns dados em edits, e o alert tenha um positive button que irá salvar essa informação e uma classe model que trabalhará esses dados, você fará a chamada da classe model, que nesse exemplo é uma classe de usuarios.
Na classe Model, além das variaveis e os getters e Setters você terá esse método:

```
public void salvar(){

    DatabaseReference banco = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    banco.child("USUARIOS").push().setValue(this);
}
```

Agora basta que você no método positiveButton do alert criar a seguinte chamada:

```
Usuarios usuarios = new Usuarios();
usuarios.setNome(editNome.getText().toString());
usuarios.setEmail(editEmail.getText().toString());
usuarios.setTelefone(editTelefone.getText().toString());
usuarios.salvar();
dismiss();//para fechar o alert
```

Ou você pode fazer essa atualização sem a classe modelo, enviando dado por dado quando for clicado no botão positivo do alert dessa maneira:

```
DatabaseReference banco = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    banco.child("USUARIOS").push().setValue("nome", etNome.getText().toString())
    .setValue("email", etEmail.getText().toString());
```

As duas opções devem funcionar, ai fica a seu creitério embora eu recomende utilizar as classes models para deixar o trabalho melhor organizado.
Qualquer dúvida estou à disposição!

Comment: Cara vc é um génio, entendi sua explicação certinho vou implementar aqui e depois mando o resultado, foi mal não ter postado o codigo do AlertDIalog pois achei ele simples de implementar na minha app por isso nem passou na minha cabeça de postar junto a pergunta, muito obg brothers.

Comment: Opah, que bom que pude ajudar !